# Why does update-notifier contains system-crash-notification?

Tags: update-manager, bug-reporting, apport

I just had "System Program Problem Detected" window appearing several times before user session even started (I have KDM with autologin to locked session).

I traced it with `xprop` to being `/usr/lib/update-notifier/system-crash-notification` which is binary (while I expected it to be some script) and belongs to `update-notifier` package (while I expected it to be somewhere from `apport*`).

P.S. Clicking on `Report problem...` button didn't do anything.

```
$ dpkg -s update-notifier | grep Version
Version: 0.147

$ dpkg -L update-notifier | grep system-crash
/usr/lib/update-notifier/system-crash-notification

$ grep RELEASE /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
```

The same question on LP: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+question/239040

Comment: What version of Ubuntu you are using, I have update-notifier installed but I don't find that file.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: whats inside /etc/default/apport , enabled should be 1 , is it?? and even in /usr/lib/update-notifier/ i dont have any system-crash-notification file

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem of error dialogs appearing at launch of the desktop.

I used krunner to show system activity (ctrl+esc on my Kubuntu). Then I found the "system-crash-notification" process and worked my way up the process tree using "jump to parent" from the right-click  menu. For me it was lightdm at the top of the tree. So I tried re-installing lightdm (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm lightdm-kde-greeter`) which completed but didn't fix the error.

Then I checked the lightdm logs in /var/log/lightdm/ and the x-0-greeter.log showed some IBus errors. Vague recollection on IBus suggested these were fine though.

So, instead I use `apt-file search system-crash-notification` to find the package responsible and see if I could dump it. Turns out that a dependency of update-notifier wasn't installed so I purged update-notifier (in aptitude, but you can do it using `sudo apt-get remove --purge update-notifier update-notifier-kde`).

That solved it and now on rebooting there are no error notification dialogs. That might not be the best way to fix this but it worked and the system is running stable.

Comment: Yes, purging `update-notifier` solves the problem with dialogs, obviously, but the question is why was this binary put in this package.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install update-notifier-kde`
Had the same issue until I installed it.  It seems it doesn't install it by default somehow.